# Creating a nested query to filter from the inital query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to create a nested query so that the query select all ordernumbers and orderid from the invoice items and then selects the items that were sub rented.

```
select
   do.orderid, do.orderno, ot.masteritemid, ot.qty
from dealorder do
inner join ordertran ot on do.orderid=ot.orderid and ot.orderid='A00M5BGA'
where ot.vendorid<>''

Select orderno, orderid from invoiceitemview where invoiceno='T646692'
```

I have tried an inner join but it does not seem to work. The first query gives me 6 items which is correct, however if I perform the join, it seems to be getting items that do not belong to the order. Hence, How would I create a nested query to get all items from the second query and then filter using the first query.

Comment: A little clarification here because your wording is a bit confusing here. You want everything filtered by invoice or by order id?

Comment: Providing a sample data with desired output can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are looking for

```
select
   do.orderid, do.orderno, ot.masteritemid, ot.qty
from dealorder do
inner join ordertran ot on do.orderid=ot.orderid and ot.orderid='A00M5BGA'
inner join (
    Select orderno, orderid from invoiceitemview where invoiceno='T646692'
) tmp ON tmp.orderno=do.orderno AND tmp.orderid=do.orderid
where ot.vendorid<>''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select do.orderid, do.orderno, ot.masteritemid, ot.qty 
from (Select orderno, orderid from invoiceitemview where invoiceno='T646692') inv
inner join dealorder do inv.orderid=do.orderid
inner join ordertran ot on do.orderid=ot.orderid and ot.orderid='A00M5BGA'
where ot.vendorid<>''
```